# How to handle touch with ExpandableListView having a group view that consists of a nested layout

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

I am trying to create an expandable list which has group items consisting of several images, textviews and buttons.

The images and textviews, I all put in one RelativeLayout and the touchevents all work so everything is fine. Then i decided to add a Button bar consisting of 3 buttons in a horizontal LinearLayout, basically creating a nested layout. But now, the group items do not respond to touch events anymore.

I am sure this has got something to do with the way the listview is inflated in the Adapter but I do not know how to do this correctly.

If someone could help me, i would be really glad!

This is the group element XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="3dp"
    android:paddingLeft="3dp"
    android:paddingRight="3dp"
    android:paddingTop="20dp">


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/item1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="#828080"
        android:focusable="false" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/item1"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:text=""
        android:textSize="20dp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/item2"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:text="" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/item5"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/item5"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/item5"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/item5"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:text="" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/item3"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/item3"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/item3"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/item3"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:text="on" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item6"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/item3"
        android:text=""
        android:textSize="15dp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/item6"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/button1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#c3d69b"
            android:padding="0dp"
            android:src="@drawable/myDrawable1" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#c3d69b"
            android:padding="0dp"
            android:src="@drawable/myDrawable2" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_margin="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#c3d69b"
            android:padding="0dp"
            android:src="@drawable/myDrawable3" />

    </LinearLayout>



</RelativeLayout>
```

EDIT

I found a workaround that suits me even better. Simply assigning listeners to the different items did the trick. This code, i added inside the Adapter for the expandablelistview

```
@Override
    protected View newGroupView(Context context, Cursor cursor, boolean isExpanded, ViewGroup parent) {
        //Log.d(TAG, "newGroupView");
        //DatabaseUtils.dumpCursor(cursor);

        final View view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.group_list_item, parent, false);

        image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageview);
        button1 = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.button_1);
        button2 = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.button_2);
        button3 = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.button_3);

        image .setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d(TAG, "image clicked");
            }
        });

        button1 .setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d(TAG, "button1 clicked");
            }
        });

        button2 .setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d(TAG, "button2  clicked");
            }
        });

        button3 .setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Log.d(TAG, "button3  clicked");

            }
        });

        return view;
    }
```

Comment: i think you are using weight property for image buttons, but you didn't mention any weightSum in linearlayout.

Comment: @SrikanthK     Thanks for mentioning,, ill add it soon to see if it works

Comment: @SrikanthK     still doesnt work, I removed the nested layout to isolate the problem so I added the buttons to the root RelativeLayout, but still no reposnse on touch.. It only works if i use the method that i posted in the EDIT (adding onClickListeners)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the adapter for the listview i added:

```
@Override
public View getGroupView(final int groupPosition, final boolean isExpanded, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
    if(convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mActivity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);
    }

    ImageButton button1 = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.button_1);

    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(isExpanded) ((ExpandableListView) parent).collapseGroup(groupPosition);
            else ((ExpandableListView) parent).expandGroup(groupPosition);
        }
    });

    return convertView;
}
```

This way you can set Onclicklisteners for whatever element you want.

Answer (score 1):

buttons are focusable that causes this strange behaviour, add the following line to button in xml

```
android:focusable="false"
```

Comment: Still doesn't work.. even with focus=false, when i out-comment the buttons, the callback for the groupitem starts working again.. It does have something to do with the buttons.. I even removed them from the nested layout and added them to the root layout

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the `android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants"` attribute into the root layout of what you're inflating.  In this case, it's your base RelativeLayout.